# Where do I get a Certificate of Veterinary Inspection (health certificate) and acclimation certificate?

Tags: dogs, travel, certificate, united-states

I have heard that I will need a Certificate of Veterinary Inspection to travel with a pet (dog) and some airlines require an acclimation certificate. Where can I obtain these certificates and is there anything I should know before attempting to get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to a checklist from the [American Veterinary Medical Association](https://www.avma.org/public/PetCare/Pages/Traveling-with-Your-Pet-FAQs.aspx) where they give a link to the USDA website to [find an accredited veterinarian](http://www.aphis.usda.gov/wps/portal/aphis/ourfocus/animalhealth?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath:/aphis_content_library/sa_our_focus/sa_animal_health/sa_vet_accreditation/ct_locate_av). If anything, I would say give the veterinarian that you normally visit a call, and ask if they're accredited to give those certificates. If they're not, you could ask if they know of another veterinarian who is.

Basically the goal of the inspection is to make sure is that you take your pet into a veterinarian for a health inspection before travelling. They might also require your dog to be up-to-date on heartworm pills. Similar to people travelling, it's really just to make sure the dog is is healthy and provide any needed vaccines to protect against diseases and parasites from where it's travelling. You might also be required to go through a follow-up visit when you return.